# How to wait for event trigger before continuing program?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm trying to write a simple calculator application in javascript/jquery and have run into a snag.  In theory, the program should store the value of the first number clicked, enter the body of the next triggered operation button (+,-,/,*) click event function, then wait for the next number button click event before executing the designated function on the two numbers.  The way that I have tried to stall the program in the operation click event function until the user chooses a second number is by entering a while loop like this:

```
$("#operation").on("click", function() {
    while(secondValue === "none") {
        continue;
    }
    operation(firstValue, secondValue);
```

The issue is that the while loop eats up all of the available memory and crashes the program before a second value can be chosen.  Is there some safe way to stall the program within the operation click event function until a second value is chosen? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you decided not to explain how and when is `secondValue` changed? I have some general idea, but I expect you to add more info on how the program exactly works. For now I can only tell you that you should execute `operation` in the event which changes `secondValue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of waiting for the next number, why not have the operation execute when the person pressed the *equal* button? That is, when you click the first button, you set something like:

```
var left_operand = 5;
```

Then when they press an operator:

```
var operator = 'add';
```

When they press another button:

```
var right_operand = 10;
```

Finally when they press equal:

```
var result = evaluate(left_operand, right_operand, operation);
```

It may be useful to use an array for the operands instead of `left` and `right`, or even a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)).

Note that you don't have to use an "equal" button if you don't want to, the point is to simply have the value set when the user types the second number. So, instead of a `while loop` when you press the operator, you might have an `if statement`, that if there's no second value, you will not perform the operation. And if there is, you will. But you should set this second value only when you submit it, and there's no need to wait. However, I think it's easier to simply assign an operator variable to the correct value when the user clicks an operation button, and use that when they click the equals button.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are performing the statements upon the click events, try this:

```
var firstValue,
    secondValue;
    enter code here

$("#operation").on("click", function() {
    if (typeof firstValue === 'undefined') {
        firstValue = **TheValue**;
    }
    else if (typeof secondValue === 'undefined') {
        secondValue = **TheValue**;
        operation(firstValue, secondValue);
        // of course, don't forget to clear both variables after you're done
    }
});
```

Your original code almost got it.
JavaScript is single thread, so your `while` loop probably hung your page.